# Enhancing the SimpleCursorAdapter to check the data in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a sqlite database. I am able to query it and get a cursor with results. It populates the data well in a list view which has 1 image view and 2 text views. However the cursor result set which has 2 columns is of text. This is shown in the 2 text views. Everything till here works fine.

Now based on the value of one of the column I need to show different images in the image view in the list item. How do I do this. As of now I am using the below code. How do I modify it to get a image view changes based on the column value?

Cursor mCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAll();
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);

```
    String[] from = new String[]{"TITLE","BODY"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2};

    SimpleCursorAdapter listValues = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, mCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(listValues );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this done using code below

listValues.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) {
            if( column == col ){ 
                ImageView img = (ImageView) ((View)view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.icon);
                if(cursor.getString(col).equals("Y"))
                {
                    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
                }
                else
                {
                    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);                        
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```